# Add Category name to Post Title (h1)

Tags: posts, categories, title

How to add Category name to post title (H1)? “PostTitle + CategoryName”?

My **h1** post title code:

```
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

Comment: Remember a post can be in multiple categories.

Answer (score 0):

I would work the code arround and do something like this.

`<h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> - <?php the_category(', '); ?></h1>`

`get_the_title();` Retrieve post title.

`the_category(', ');` Displays links to categories, each category separated by a comma (if more than one).

Documentation can be founded here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Why `echo get_the_title();` and not just `the_title()`?

Comment: I guess it's a developper preference right here when you do not need to work with the before and after filter for the title. At this point of just rendering a string, it would be how the person like to code his or her theme based on his or her way of learning.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions you can use.

### Change it in the theme

If you can just modify the line that is printing the title, then do it. You can replace it with:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_category(); ?></h1>
```

And if the categories shouldn't  be linked, then you can use this:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    if ( ! empty($categories) ) {
        foreach ( $categories as $term ) {
            echo esc_html( $term->name ) . ' ';
        }
    }
?></h1>
```

### If you can't change the theme

Or you don't want to, because there are many, many places you'd have to change, then you can use `the_title` filter:

```
function add_categories_to_the_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) && 'post' == get_post_type( $id ) ) {  // it will work only for posts on single page, but you can modify this condition
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $cats_string = '';
        if ( ! empty($categories) ) {
            foreach ( $categories as $term ) {
                $cats_string .= $term->name . ' ';
            }
        }
        if ( $cats_string ) {
            $title .= ' - ' . $cats_string;
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_categories_to_the_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I like the_title filter, but here is a bug. Why it adds category names not only to post titles but also to category bar in the menu :(

Comment: @Seryozha because that’s the condition. You didn’t mention what titles and where exactly you want to change, so...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me, how to add category names only in posts, but not in the navigation menu with "the_title filter"?

Comment: Should they be modified on archives also?

Comment: No, only in single posts and only in h1

Comment: @Seryozha OK, I've updated my answer - it should be enough.